# Is checking if key is in dictionary and getting it's value in the same "if" safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I think this is safe:

```
if key in test_dict:
    if test_dict[key] == 'spam':
        print('Spam detected!')
```

but is this safe?

```
if key in test_dict and test_dict[key] == 'spam':
    print('Spam detected!')
```

It should do the same thing because condition checking is lazy in python. It won't try to get the value (and raise an exception because there's no such key in the dict) because the first condition is already not satisfied. But can I rely on the lazyness and use the second example in my programs?

Comment: yes, both snippets are equivalent and "safe".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, Python would short circuit if first expression result in False, that is it would not evaluate the second expression in the `if` condition.

But a better way to do your condition would be to use `.get()` , which returns `None` if key is not present in dictionary . Example -

```
if test_dict.get(key) == 'spam':
    print('Spam detected!')
```

Comment: It's not equivalent - spam key may have value 'None'.

Comment: In that case as well its equivalent , the condition would not be satisfied. `None` is not equal to spam .

Comment: @AnandSKumar So, the only situation in which it wouldn't work is when i'm searching for None?

Comment: Yes, but even in tht case `.get()` accepts a second parameter, which is what would be returned by default, if the key is not found, when the default parameter (second argument) is not specified, `None` is returned. When checking against `None` you can use a different default value. But if you are cheking for whether key is present in dicitonary or not alone ,using `in` would be better.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Only one condition/expression?

Comment: I would bet it is actually slower

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As I understand now, because it's equivalent to what I used in my question (except the situation when I'm searching for None) and is shorter.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I ***think*** that would depend on how many times the key is found in the dictionary , right? And in either case, I doubt this would become a bottleneck for a program.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, .get would get closer when the key did exist but when it did not using the if and would be much more efficient

Answer (score 3):

`and test_dict[key] == 'spam':` will only be evaluated if `if key in test_dict` is `True`, it will behave exactly the same as your first code where you have the if nested.

When you use `and` both sides of the expression must be True so if the `key in test_dict` returns False then the code will short circuit.

Using your `and` approach is actually the most efficient especially when the left hand side of the expression is False:

```
In [13]: d = {k:k for k in range(10000)}
In [14]: timeit 99999 in d and d[100] == "foo"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 48.2 ns per loop

In [15]: timeit d.get(9000) == "foo" 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 155 ns per loop
In [16]: timeit 100  in d and d[100] == "foo
10000000 loops, best of 3: 119 ns per loo    
In [17]: timeit d.get(100) == "foo"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 141 ns per loop
```

Comment: Yeah but more efficient is simply  `d[100] == "foo"` but with a try except round it.  Unless most of the keys are not in the dict.